# HAproxy / rewrite local ip to external ip

Tags: data, haproxy

I have a local cluster and an external client on the internet. The solution is communicating on several ports, but though a HAproxy upstream LB.
The cluster handles many other solutions on the local network.

In this case, the cluster sends its local IPs back to HAproxy and further to the client on the internet. The communication stops, because the client can't find the "local servers". Is there a way, the HAproxy can rewrite a local IP to a well defined external IP? In the end, it's all about port numbers.

Comment: I believe this would not be possible and it would be better either way to do this translation in your web application. Let the application determine that it is behind a NAT address and make the necessary modifications.

Comment: Well, It's a dataplatform with a lot of nodes with a lot of internal jobs, so I have to do this right. We are operating in "names" and not IPs. I don't know how to rewrite a name on the way out, but is'nt similar to IPs?